# Black Screen on lubuntu 17.10 after display resolution change, a half solution

Tags: 17.10, display-resolution, screen

I have installed lubuntu 17.10 on an old computer to do little things only (athlon XP SSE 1 and radeon 9100). After installing all is good but a change in display resolution gives me a black screen with mouse arrow when rebooting.

I´ve tried lot of things found on internet to fix this error (update, upgrade, xrandr, nomodeset, etc) but none left me change display resolution again.

At last I´ve found by chance how to do, and want to share because is a workaround I didn´t find browsing. The trick is switching between text and X interface, so I press CTRL+ALT+F1 to get text and then CTRL+ALT+F7 to go back to an X working interface where I can change resolution again.

Problem is lubuntu continues booting with black screen. Now I need help to do this switch at the start of lubuntu without using the keyboard.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `display.sh` or `monitor.sh` script and test it to make sure it works as intended.

Then add a fullpathame to the script as a `display-setup-script` entry in your `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`.

Example of a `monitor.sh` script (modify to match your manual commands that work):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                           

cvt 1920 1080 60
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
```

The `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf` file:

```
[Seat:*]
display-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/monitor.sh
```

**Important note:**

Be sure the script works.  If the script has errors your **Lightdm** GUI login manager will fail with a `The system is running in low-graphics mode` error. If that happens use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and comment out the line with the script while you fix the script.  You can restart lightdm with:

```
$ sudo systemctrl restart lightdm
```

Comment: Thanks James, now I can do an autostart with your method, but I don´t know the command that mimics CTRL+ALT+F1.

Comment: I'm not clear on where you're having a problem.  It sounds as if you have tested the process and the script works.  The purpose of the `ctrl+alt+F3` is a way to get to the console to type commands to fix any problems if there are problems.  If there isn't any problems, there's no need to go to the console to fix anything.  If there are problems, the hit the key stoke to get to a console to fix them.

Comment: @ What to do if Ctrl+Alt+F3 does not work? The screen is still blank when doing this. I have to restart to get the graphics work again...